# Set a sleep interval between each resolve with co?

Tags: javascript, generator, co

I'm using `co` to execute a generator with a bunch of http requests:

```
co(function *(){
  // resolve multiple promises in parallel 
  var a = httpRequest(...);
  var b = httpRequest(...);
  var c = httpRequest(...);
  var res = yield [a, b, c];
  console.log(res);
}).catch(onerror);
```

Is there a way for me to introduce a second of sleep between each http request? Thanks.

Comment: so you want them to execute sequentially, not in parallel?

Comment: or still in parallel - just each delayed by 1 second?

Comment: Sequentially, one after another with a second of interval, ideally. Essentially I don't want the server side to hate me.

Comment: hmm, I don't know if `co` is the right approach here then..the above example is to be used for resolving promises in parallel. Could try `reduce`-ing the array of promises

Comment: No, I believe the above code will resolve promised sequentially. I think I'm pretty sure about that because the `next` is called when the previous promise is fulfilled.

Comment: Why do you want to use `co`?

Comment: `co` is not a must. It's just to avoid callback hell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Each yield - return new promise with dilay (in promise - you have to fire resolve or reject acording to httpRequest callback)
Try in this way

```
co(function *(){
var a = yield new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function () {
        //rosolve or reject this promise in callback of httpRequest();
    }, 1000)
});
var b = yield new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function () {
        //rosolve or reject this promise in callback of httpRequest();
    }, 1000)
});
var c = yield new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function () {
        //rosolve or reject this promise in callback of httpRequest();
    }, 1000)
});
var res = [a, b, c];
    console.log(res); 
}).catch(onerror);
```